# ListLinePlot gives the correct values but N doesn't

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I have solved a set of 6 differential equations with DSolve. When I use the table command and produce the results of one of the equations given by DSolve, the ListLinePlot command gives me the correct plot that I expect. However, if I use N function and then plot the results, incorrect values will be observed. My intention is to extract the values of ListLinePlot so that I can use them for further calculation.

The function is as following (sorry if it is huge):

```
 ut1[s] = {1/2 (-((263065237316028000000 RootSum[
              635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 E^((s #1)/
                 556815000) + E^((s #1)/556815000) #1^2)/(
               384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                773240378428000 #1^3 + 
                3 #1^5) &] (-526130474632056000000 F RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                  58662093574000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 E^((\
    \[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1 + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^3)/(
                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] + 
               263065237316028000000 F RootSum[

                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                  58662093574000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 E^((\
    \[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1 + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^3)/(
                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (384506509054825843402500000000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     327958095640000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    + 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] + 
               292268684265343371301878659417760000000000000 F RootSum[

                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                  E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                  19729892798702100000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   19303 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 E^((\
    \[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^2)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    #1 + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] - 
               10253506908128689157400000000000 F RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                  19729892798702100000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   19303 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (1653562369200 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^2)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    #1 + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] + 
               5126753454064344578700000000000 F RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                  19729892798702100000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   19303 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (384506509054825843402500000000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     327958095640000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    + 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (1653562369200 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^2)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    #1 + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] + 
               14499825902348383627117920000000000 F RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 E^((\
    \[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1 + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^3)/(
                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 E^((\
    \[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^2)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    #1 + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (-13183080310451171773800000000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     45764253640000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    #1 + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] + 
               28119305232054186819732252000000000 F RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                  E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                  58662093574000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(

                  384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (179436370892252060254500000000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     127325030000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    #1 + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] - 
               27187173566903219300846100000000000 F RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (1653562369200 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^2)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    #1 + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (-13183080310451171773800000000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     45764253640000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    #1 + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] RootSum[
                 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                   384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                   386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (179436370892252060254500000000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                     127325030000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                     E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                      14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 \
    #1 + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 
                     3 #1^5) \
    &]))/(-1394910749393204308212476277803143152000000000000000 RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 
               E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (

                58662093574000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1 + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^3)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] + 
             1394910749393204308212476277803143152000000000000000 RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                58662093574000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(

                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] - 
             2718475301231819699070654925187350039633080000000000000000000\
    0 RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 
               E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                19729892798702100000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                 19303 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[

               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                1653562369200 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] - 
             1348670614054203060426427340417403600000000000000000 RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                1653562369200 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (-13183080310451171773800000000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   45764253640000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                   E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                    14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 \
    + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] - 
             70700371442715913809120000000 RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                19729892798702100000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                 19303 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 

                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (-2207159723814153613400000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   386620189214000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                   E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                    14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 \
    + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] - 
             3507536497547040000 RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1 + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^3)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (-13183080310451171773800000000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   45764253640000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                   E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                    14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 \
    + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (-2207159723814153613400000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   386620189214000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                   E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                    14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 \
    + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &])) - (RootSum[
            635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
              384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
              386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
             19729892798702100000000 E^((s #1)/556815000) + 
              19303 E^((s #1)/556815000) #1^2)/(
             384504301895102029248886600000000 + 773240378428000 #1^2 + 
              3 #1^4) &] \
    (-21920151319900752847640899456332000000000000000 F RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 
               E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1 + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^3)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] + 
             21920151319900752847640899456332000000000000000 F RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                    14848400) #1^2)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 \
    + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &]^2 - 
             769013018109651686805000000000000 F RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                1653562369200 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] + 
             384506509054825843402500000000000 F RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (384506509054825843402500000000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   327958095640000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                   E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                    14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                   773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (-48228902435000 \
    E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                1653562369200 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] + 
             41100283724813911589326686480622500000000000000 F RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 
               E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400)/(

                384504301895102029248886600000000 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^2 + 3 #1^4) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, (
                1653562369200 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2)/(
                384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 + 
                 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2 + 
                 386620189214000 #1^4 + #1^6 &, \
    (179436370892252060254500000000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) + 
                   127325030000000 E^((\[Pi] #1)/14848400) #1^2 + 
                   E^((\[Pi] #1)/
                    14848400) #1^4)/(384504301895102029248886600000000 #1 \
    + 773240378428000 #1^3 + 3 #1^5) &] - 
             2 F RootSum[
               635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 + 
                 384504301895102029248886600000000 #1^2}
```

Now I establish the plot as:

```
Re1 = Flatten[
   Table[ut1[s] /. F -> 10000, {s , 0 , (r*\[Pi])/2 , (r*\[Pi])/
     500}]];

xpoints1 = Table[s , {s , 0 , (r*\[Pi])/2 , (r*\[Pi])/500}];

RE7 = Transpose@{xpoints1 , Re1};
```

If I use ListLinePlot command, the results are perfect. But If I use

```
N[RE7]//ListLinePlot
```

I will get incorrect values. 
Now the question is: 1- How this happens? and 2- How to extract the correct data given by ListLinePlot?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, your ut1[s] was truncated (incorrect Mma expression). Next, once your see huge integers like 635805494085519074310026089203000000000000000 it imediatelly suggest that this is precision issue. So, just try N[RE7, 30]//ListLinePlot or something like to force Mathematica use precision arithmetic.

Comment: This error pops up 
N::meprec: "Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating {{0,0},<<49>>,<<201>>}."

Comment: Increase it before evaluating N[], say $MaxExtraPrecision = 5000.

Comment: The same error exists.

Comment: Just confirms that this really is a precision issue.  Increase it even more. Try to convert RootSum into Root objects (with Normal). Then again try N[ ]. Try to identify which part causes a problem,... Probably the case probably is more interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Normal does the job. I could obtain the same results as Table.